# Search csv file by Html form and php

Tags: php, html, forms, csv, search

I trying to make a search form to search a `Name` column in CSV file.

Below is my code

`search.html` page

```
     <form  method="post" action="php/search.php"  id="searchform"> 
              <input  type="text" name="name" id="name"> 
              <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" data-formId="searchform"> 
           </form>
```

and this is `search.php`:

```
<?php


$name = trim($_POST['name']);

echo "<html><body><table>\n\n";
$f = fopen("CopyofDirectory_JED123456.csv", "r");
$result = false;

while (($row = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {


if ($row[0] == $name){
echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($row as $cell) {


                echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";


}

}
fclose($f);
echo "\n</table></body></html>";
```

My problem is the result when I press the search button, the result is an empty page.

It seems like the POST name is not seen by the PHP code!

Please note that my csv file contains the following columns

```
name, extension, ID
```

When I put the if condition, nothing appear to me.

And when I remove if condition, all data stored in csv file appear.

Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: so you're sure that the name is not in the POST superglobal? what does `var_dump($_POST['name'])` say?

Comment: when I put the if condition, nothing appear to me.
and when I remove if condition, all data stored in csv file appear. @ZathrusWriter

Comment: that's not really what I was asking though - what's the output of the dump?

Comment: @ZathrusWriter the same string written in the "name" text field. in the form

Comment: therefore the POST name IS being seen by the PHP code and the problem is elsewhere